# I have to create a 2-D array of Checkboxes in java and arrange them in 2 columns using grid layout. Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, grid-layout, jcheckbox

I have create a JPanel and have added the checkboxes to the panel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
```

This is my work up till now, This is a 1-D array, And it shows a single column of checkboxes onthe left side. 
How can i add another column just alongside the existing one.

```
public class UserInterface extends JFrame 
{

    private JPanel club;
    private JCheckBox[] check = new JCheckBox[10];

    public UserInterface()
    {
        super("SPORTS CLUB");
        club=new JPanel();

        add(club);

        club.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,2));

        check[0] = new JCheckBox("101");
        check[1] = new JCheckBox();
        check[2] = new JCheckBox();
        check[3] = new JCheckBox();
        check[4] = new JCheckBox();
        check[5] = new JCheckBox();
        check[6] = new JCheckBox();
        check[7] = new JCheckBox();
    check[8] = new JCheckBox();

        check[9] = new JCheckBox();

        club.setAlignmentY(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            club.add(check[i]);
        }
    }


}
```

This is my class Main containing the main() function;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        UserInterface data=new UserInterface();
        data.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        data.setSize(300,200);
        data.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Any little help is appreciated, Even references are welcomed.

Comment: Hint: you already have a loop that **adds** your check array slots to club. Why on earth are you not using another loop (or the same loop) to crate your checkboxes?

Answer (score 2):

> How can i add another column

Change

```
// 10 rows, 2 columns
club.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,2));
```

to:

```
// variable number of rows, 2 columns
club.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
```

Note that when you do this, every odd checkbox goes on the left and even on the right, and so if you want specific check boxes in a specific column, then order of addition matters.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: with the `0` parameter, there's no need to worry about number of checkboxes -- it becomes more "idiot-proof"

Answer (score 0):

So if I interpreted your question right, you want 2 columns of checkboxes right?
First of all don´t use Arrays for tasks like this, they are not dynamic which makes the code kinda ugly. You don´t even need it anyway.

First you want to create a JPanel with the layout manager grid:

```
JPanel grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
```

Now fill the panel with Checkboxes and give each Checkbox it´s own Action Command. This way you can use Listeners way better.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
JCheckbox c = new JCheckbox();
c.setActionCommand(i);
grid.add(c);
}
```

This is a way more elegant solution than using an array. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help @Alexander